# Installing Jekyll on CentOS 7 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, github, centos, jekyll

I am trying to install Jekyll on CentOS 7 so I did a clean install of the OS and started to following this:

```
http://www.resilvered.com/blog/2014/08/26/Installing-Jekyll-on-CentOS-7/
```

Step 1 worked but if I run step two I am getting this error:

```
[jxsmith@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install nodejs npm ruby ruby-devel rubygems git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
[jxsmith@localhost ~]$
```

can someone please tell me how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update yum after clean installation ?  If not then please update it and follow same steps. It will work.

Login as root and apply command `yum update`